# Java Retrieve List Payload from a Provided Index

Tags: java, data-structures, nodes

I'm creating a linked list and I'm trying to figure out how I can write a method that will return the node payload for a specific index.  Just how vectors have get(int index) I'd like to implement something similar. Also with this functionality I can easily have an add(int index, e Element) as well, which for a circular doubly linked list will be super handy.

In my DynamicNode file I've implemented it this way:

```
    public class DynamicNode {
    private Object info;
    private DynamicNode next, previous;
    private int position;

    public DynamicNode(Object x) {
        info = x;
    }

    public Object getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public DynamicNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public DynamicNode getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setInfo(Object x) {
        info = x;
    }

    public void setNext(DynamicNode n) {
        next = n;
    }

    public void setPrevious(DynamicNode m) {
        previous = m;
    }

    public void setPosition(int x) {
        position = x;
    }
}
```

I have a counter in my LinkedList.java file that increments and decrements the number of nodes so the index gets passed along.

The only way I could think that a get(int index) statement would work would be to run a loop in the get method that checks the index of the node and when the right index is matched it returns the information associated with the node, but that seems like an awfully intensive process.

Thanks in advance, and if there is more information you need just post and I'll do my best to fill in the gaps.

My insert method

```
public void insert(DynamicNode node) {
        //set node's previous node to the last node entered
        node.setPrevious(last);

        //set previous node's next to node
        last.setNext(node);

        //set node's next to first node
        node.setNext(first);

        //increase numNodes pool
        numNodes++;

        //sets new last node 
        last = node;

        //sets node position
        node.setPosition(numNodes);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the main disadvantage of linked lists: random access by index is O(n) rather than being O(1) for lists backed by an array. That's just how they work.

You could make things better by uing a skip list, but it would make things more complex, and need more memory.

Note than storing the index in each node makes it worse, since inserting a node at the first index, which should be O(1) without the index stored, becomes O(n) with the index, since you need to visit every node of the list to increment their index. By storing this index, you're basically taking the worse part from both linked lists and array lists.

Why are you implementing a linked list, and not using the standard `java.util.LinkedList`?

Comment: To answer your last question first it's for class and we have to create our own LinkedList file.

Could you explain a little more about the O(n) and O(1)? Do you mean that the access is rather than going sequentially in an array to get to the index, it's basically walking through the whole list to get to the index? 

That makes sense, but my idea is to implement the index when I insert the node. I'll edit my OP with the insert() method as it's too long to put in a response.  But that way the node index is part of the payload along with info, next, and previous.

Comment: Inserting a node at the beginning of a Linked list should be a constant time operation (O(1)). You just have to create a new node, set its next pointer to the current first node, and you're done. Since you're storing the position of every node in the node itself, this operation becomes more complex: you need to additionally iterate over all the nodes of the list to increment their position. This makes it O(n). You lose all the (little) advantage a linked list has over an array list by doing that. And I don't see what you gain, since you have to iterate over the nodes anyway to implement get(i)

Comment: Ah, I fully understand now.  That makes sense, but when I add a node I'm adding it to the back of the list, not the front, so in that regard it's not incremental the position every time I add a node, but rather if I add a node in the middle of the list.  I was hoping that it would be a simple(ish) method that I could write to pull the node at a specific index, but if the way to do that is to iterate over the nodes until I found node.index(x), the way to iterate over the nodes is to node.getNext() and count++ until I reach it. So the node index is a waste of time. 

Thanks!

Comment: So I went back and changed my code and rather than working off an index I worked my insert(index) off a built in counter and it worked like a charm, and seems to be much easier than implementing an index. It's a little more work to insert in the middle, or get something out but it works great! Thanks again for your help.